# Closed formula for integral

Tags: integration, reference-request, definite-integrals

Mathematica can evaluate

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{ \ln^{p} {x} \sin^{q} {x}}{x^r}dx $$

for all $p,q,r \in \mathrm{N}$ when $q \geq r>c, c \equiv q-r \ (\textrm{mod} \ 2)  $, but can't give general formula. Any references would be appreciated. Also, any hints on how to do $p=q=r=1$ case? All results are some combination of a fraction, Euler–Mascheroni and logarithms.

So, is there a formula in spirit of :

[image]

**UPDATE**

I changed the notation a bit here to match Raymond Manzoni's first reference:  integral converges for $p\geq q$ :

1. for $p$ odd (even) and $q$ even(odd)

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\ln^{r}\! x \sin^{p} \! x }{x^q} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{(-1)^{r} (-1)^{\lfloor \frac{p-q}{2} \rfloor} }{ \Gamma(q) 2^p}  \sum\limits_{i=0}^{r} \binom{r}{i} \frac{(-1)^{r-i} (r-i)!}{2^{r-i}} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{p}{2} \rfloor - \text{mod}(2p-q,2)} \! \! \! \! \!  \! \! \! \! \!  2(-1)^k \binom{p}{k}(p-2k)^{q-1} \sum\limits_{t=0}^{\lfloor \frac{r-i+1}{2} \rfloor} \frac{\text{Li}_{2t}(-1)\ln^{r-i+1-2t}\left(\frac{1}{(p-2k)^2}\right) }{(r-i+1-2t)!} \sum\limits_{\lambda \vdash i} \psi_0^{m_1}(q) \psi_1^{m_2}(q)\cdot \ldots\cdot  \psi_{i-1}^{m_{l(\lambda)} }(q) \frac{\binom{i}{m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_{l(\lambda)}}}{m_1! m_2! \cdot \ldots\cdot ,m_{l(\lambda)}!} (-1)^{m_1+m_2+\ldots +m_{l(\lambda)}}$$

2. for $p$ odd (even) and $q$ odd(even)

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\ln^{r}\! x \sin^{p} \! x }{x^q} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{(-1)^{r} (-1)^{ \frac{2p-q + \text{mod}(p,2)}{2}} }{ \Gamma(q) 2^{p-1}}  \sum\limits_{i=0}^{r} \binom{r}{i}  (-1)^{r-i} (r-i)! \sum\limits_{k=1}^{ \frac{p +\text{mod}(p,2)}{2}}  \!  \! \! \! \! \!  2(-1)^k \binom{p}{\frac{p +\text{mod}(p,2)}{2}- k}(2k-\text{mod}(p,2))^{q-1} \sum\limits_{t=0}^{\lfloor \frac{r-i+1}{2} \rfloor} \frac{\text{Li}_{2t}(-1) \sum\limits_{m=0}^{\lfloor \frac{r-i-2t}{2} \rfloor} \binom{r-i-2t+1}{2m+1} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)^{2m+1} \ln^{r-i-2t-2m} \left( \frac{1}{2k -\text{mod}(p,2) } \right) }{(r-i-2t+1)!} \sum\limits_{\lambda \vdash i} \psi_0^{m_1 }(q) \psi_1^{m_2 }(q)\cdot \ldots\cdot  \psi_{i-1}^{m_{l(\lambda)} }(q) \frac{\binom{i}{m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_{l(\lambda)}}}{m_1! m_2! \cdot \ldots\cdot ,m_{l(\lambda)}!} (-1)^{m_1+m_2+\ldots +m_{l(\lambda)}}$$

where $\text{Li}$ is polylogarithm, $\psi$ is polygamma, and the last sum is over all partitions $\lambda = \left(1^{m_1} 2^{m_2} \ldots \right) $ and $l(\lambda)$ is partition length.

fell free to tidy up and improove if you want, I don't have the will right now.

Comment: Just found here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html , formula (37) for above integral without logarithm part. Amazing formula

Comment: Hint: consider your general formula for $\;\displaystyle F_a(b)=\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\sin^{a}(x)}{x^b}dx\;$ and compute the $p$-th derivative to obtain $\;\displaystyle \left(\frac d{db}\right)^p F_a(b)=(-1)^p\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\ln^p(x)\,\sin^{a}(x)}{x^b}dx\;$ (since $\;\displaystyle\frac d{db} x^{-b}=\frac d{db} e^{-b\ln(x)}=-\ln(x)x^{-b}$).

Comment: Thank you very much, that's it. I was expecting something simple. I'll write the general formula now.

Comment: Glad it helped @nik. The integral $F_a(b)$ on the other side was obtained by Wolstenholme and this is detailed in [Edwards' book p.209](https://archive.org/stream/treatiseonintegr02edwauoft#page/208/mode/2up) while a generalization appears in Nathan's [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.5911.pdf). Fine continuation,

Comment: I finally got my formula! Unfortunately that partial derivation doesn't work becasue it's a definite integral, BUT using the first reference you gave me I had a clear start to do it from scratch. Thanks you so much! It took me a few days to get everything right, I'll just write everything without a proof, because it would be too long.

Comment: Funny formula. :-) Congratulations, if it's correct.

Comment: thanks! here is above code notebook in case it copies poorly  [int](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=31946379812751133432)

Comment: @nik: Quite an impressive formula... so that now I'll have to try to simplify it... (this weekend I hope). Thanks to share your results anyway!

Comment: a nice and full proof would be a dozen pages long, I don't know if it is worth it, what do you think? anyway, it basically boils down to finding some limits at infinity, tedious work, but it can be done. I doubt there is any non trivial simplification.

Comment: @nik: Wolstenholme's proof appears indeed rather long while your initial formula for $F_a(b)$ is rather short if correct... (I didn't even check any of them yet). So : no clear opinion at this point but I got curious! (... to find a shorter answer not to provide a dozen page proof! ;-))

Comment: I'm glad you are interested, I will write a proof sketch tomorrow.

Comment: @nik: Nice, answers by the OP are appreciated here! (the edit from your question could have been an answer). Excellent continuation,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the proof and Mathematica code to play with. Took me some time to write all this. Thank you again Raymond Manzoni for that nice Edwards book(s) refference, couldn't have done it without it. It would be nice to see a proof for idenetities (37) and (38) in paper, one proof is in Edwards book but it's not too elegant, one way is to reduce it to hypergeometric identity [http://functions.wolfram.com/07.31.03.0032.01](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/03/01/05/0009/) but I don't know how to prove that identity. Also the final expressions are equivalent to ones I wrote above without proof, but more elegant.

You can downolad it here : [download link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05475182588084617834)

and the .tex file here: [download link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=55626119877128854245)

This code is also much nicer than the last one, you can download the Mathematica notebook here [download link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=61055991359817872149)

Comment: +1: our methods are rather different but it seems that we both need the Bell polynomials at the end...

Answer (score 3):

> Lemma: If $\,q\,$ is a real value then : 
>   \begin{align}
> \tag{1} C(q):=\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x^q}\;dx=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}2q\right)\,\Gamma(1-q),\quad 0<q<1\\
> \tag{2} S(q):=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^q}\;dx=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2q\right)\,\Gamma(1-q),\quad 0<q<2\\
> \end{align}

(ref [DLMF $5.9.6$ and $5.9.7$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9#E7) or table $150$ of de Haan's $1867$ "Nouvelles tables d'intégrales définies"
or use the substitution $\,x:=it\,$ and analytic continuation : $\;\displaystyle\Gamma(1-q)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t^q}\,dt=-i\int_0^{i\infty} \frac{e^{ix}}{x^q}i^q\,dx=-i\;e^{\large{\frac {\pi}2q\,i}}\int_0^{i\infty} \frac{e^{ix}}{x^q}\,dx\; $)

Expanding powers of $\;\sin(x)=\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ with the binomial theorem gives us :
\begin{align}
\tag{3}\sin(x)^{2n}&=\frac 2{2^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k}\binom{2n}{k}\cos\left((2n-2k)x\right)\\
\tag{4}\sin(x)^{2n+1}&=\frac 2{2^{2n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k}\binom{2n+1}{k}\sin\left((2n+1-2k)x\right)\\
\end{align}
allowing us to generalize $(2)$ to $\;\displaystyle F_p(q):=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)^p}{x^q}\;dx\ $ with $p$ a positive integer :
\begin{align}
\text{for}\ p=2n&:&F_{p}(q)&:=\frac 2{2^p}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k}\binom{p}{k}\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos\left((p-2k)x\right)}{x^q}\;dx\\
\tag{5}&& F_{p}(q)&=\frac 2{2^p}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}2q\right)\,\Gamma(1-q)\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k}\binom{p}{k}(p-2k)^{q-1}\\
\\
\text{for}\ p=2n+1&:&F_{p}(q)&:=\frac 2{2^p}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k}\binom{p}{k}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\left((p-2k)x\right)}{x^q}\;dx\\
\tag{6}&& F_{p}(q)&=\frac 2{2^p}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2q\right)\,\Gamma(1-q)\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k}\binom{p}{k}(p-2k)^{q-1}\\
\end{align}

But these are simply the imaginary (for $p$ even) or real (for $p$ odd) part of :
$$\tag{7}G_{p}(q)=\frac 2{2^p}i^q\,\Gamma(1-q)\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k}\binom{p}{k}(p-2k)^{q-1},\quad n:=\left\lfloor\frac p2\right\rfloor$$

To evaluate the wished $\;\displaystyle I(p,q,r):=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)^r\sin(x)^p}{x^q}\;dx\;$ for nonnegative integer values $r$ and since $\;\displaystyle\frac d{dq} x^{-q}=-\ln(x)\,x^{-q}\;$ we need only to use :
$$
\tag{8}I(p,q,r)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)^r\sin(x)^p}{x^q}\;dx=\left(-\frac d{dq}\right)^{\large r} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)^p}{x^q}\;dx$$
and evaluate the imaginary (for $p$ even) or real (for $p$ odd) part of :
$$\tag{9}\left(-\frac d{dq}\right)^{\large r} G_{p}(q)=\frac 2{2^p}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k}\binom{p}{k}\,\left(-\frac d{dq}\right)^{\large r}\left(\Gamma(1-q)((p-2k)\,i)^{q-1}\right)$$
Setting $\;K:=(p-2k)\,i\;\ $ let's study $\quad\displaystyle 
f_r=f_r(k,p,q)=\left(-\frac d{dq}\right)^{\large r}\; \left(\Gamma(1-q)\,K^{q-1}\right)$.

The [digamma function $\psi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) defined by $\;\psi(x):=(\ln\Gamma(x))'\;$ allows us to rewrite $\;\displaystyle \left(-\frac d{dq}\right)\Gamma(1-q)=\Gamma(1-q)\,\psi(1-q)\;$ and provides these first results :
\begin{align}
f_1&=\Gamma(1-q)\,K^{q-1}\left[\psi(1-q)-\ln(K)\right]\\
f_2&=\Gamma(1-q)\,K^{q-1}\left[\left(\psi(1-q)-\ln(K)\right)^2+\psi^{(1)}(1-q)\right]\\
f_3&=\Gamma(1-q)\,K^{q-1}\left[\left(\psi(1-q)-\ln(K)\right)^3+3\left(\psi(1-q)-\ln(K)\right)\psi^{(1)}(1-q)+\psi^{(2)}(1-q)\right]\\
f_4&=\Gamma(1-q)\,K^{q-1}\left[\left(\psi(1-q)-\ln(K)\right)^4+6\left(\psi(1-q)-\ln(K)\right)^2\psi^{(1)}(1-x)+4\left(\psi(1-q)-\\\ln(K)\right)\psi^{(2)}(1-q)+3\left(\psi^{(1)}\right)^2+\psi^{(3)}(1-q)\right]\\
\end{align}
The expressions between brackets are obtained from the previous ones using the recurrence : $\,x_{n+1}(t)=x_1(t)\;x_n(t)+x_n(t)'\;$ with $\,x_1(t)=\psi(t)-\ln(K)$.
($t\,$ is actually $\,1-q$)

We obtain thus the [complete Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Examples_2) (with $x_1(t)=\psi(t)-\ln(K),\,x_2(t)=\psi^{(1)}(t),\cdots,$ $x_r(t)=\psi^{(r-1)}(t),\cdots$) and may write 
$$\tag{10}f_r(k,p,q)=\Gamma(1-q)\,((p-2k)\,i)^{q-1}\;B_r(x_1(1-q),x_2(1-q),\cdots,x_r(1-q))$$
allowing us to use the different expressions from the [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Recurrence_relations) and obtain the wished result :
$$\tag{11}I(p,q,r)=\begin{cases}p\ \text{odd}&|\quad\Re\\p\ \text{even}&|\quad\Im\end{cases}\ \frac 2{2^p}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k}\binom{p}{k}\,f_r(k,p,q)$$ 
The exponential generating function for the terms between brackets gives us for example :
\begin{align}
\tag{12}g(z)&:=\exp\left((\psi(t)-\ln(K))\frac{z}{1!}+\psi^{(1)}(t)\frac{z^2}{2!}+\psi^{(2)}(t)\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)\\
&=1+\left(\psi(t)-\ln(K)\right)\frac z{1!}+\left((\psi(t)-\ln(K))^2+\psi^{(1)}(t)\right)\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots\\
\end{align}
$\qquad\qquad$(we have simply $\;\displaystyle g(t)=\frac{\Gamma(t)}{K^t}\,$ when $z=t$)

Comment: I am not entirely satisfied by the end but it's late so... (I checked the results up to $(7)$, sorry for the additional checking work btw :-))

Comment: +1, great to see your work on this!  very nice to see an extension for  $0 <q < 1$, I'll try to upgrade my result soon, the formula I got is good only for integers. I'll post the tex file if you like to make any edits yourself

Comment: Glad it helped in any way @nik! I'll look at your updated tex or pdf file but take all your time for this. Excellent continuation,